# Need Quick Help With Product Category Page

Tags: php, categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I wanted to have some additional text below the displayed products on the product category page on my website. I didn't know how to do this the smart way, so I just shoved some text into the taxonomy-product-cat.php theme file.

Here is the code for that page:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

 ?>

<?php get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' ); ?>

<div style="margin-left:645px;"><?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { 
    ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT( array( 'use_current_page' => true ) );
} ?></div>

<?php tf_woocommerce_product_taxonomy_content(); ?>

<div id="prodcatdesc"><div style="padding-top:85px;"><hr><p>My text that I wrote is here.</p></br>
</div></div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' ); ?>

<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

So, this works, but it also adds the text I shoved in there into every product category page on my site. What I am wondering is, how can I constrain the div text I added to only one specific category page?

The theme I am using is Sooperstore if that helps. This little nuisance is stopping me from expanding my entire store :(

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For Woocommerce product categories, use

```
<?php if ( is_product_category() ) {

 echo '<div id="prodcatdesc">';

  if ( is_product_category( 'shirts' ) ) {
    echo 'Hi! Take a look at our sweet tshirts below.';

  } elseif ( is_product_category( 'games' ) ) {

    echo 'Hi! Hungry for some gaming?';
  } else {

    echo 'Hi! Check our our products below.';

    echo '</div>';
  }

} ; ?>
```

Or, for just one,

```
<?php 

     if ( is_product_category( 'shirts' ) ) {

        echo '<div id="prodcatdesc">';
        echo 'Hi! Take a look at our sweet tshirts below.';
        echo '</div>';
        } ;

 ?>
```

See https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Put your inline styles, i.e. `<div style="padding-top:85px;"><hr><p>` in CSS.